# MFC: CDialog from CPropertyPage

Tags: mfc, cdialog, cpropertysheet

I have CPropertySheet which contain multiple CPropertyPage as tabs. In one of the CPropertyPage I have a button and clicking on the button launches a CDialog. I am trying to get the control to CPropertyPage calling GetParent() method inside the CDialog class methods but somehow I don't get the right parent window and when I try to access the members of CPropertypage it throws an Access Violation Exception.

Following is the code I have used:

```
CDialog *parentDialog = (CDialog *)GetParent(); 

CPropertyPage *parentPage = (CPropertyPage *)parentDialog->GetParent(); 

DResourceStateMgr dSrcStateMgr(parentPage->m_psp.hInstance); 
                                              // throws Access Violation exception.
```

Same thing used to work in the Visual studio 2008 but when I moved to visual studio 2013 it throws the exception.

Comment: First thing to check is the `m_hWnd` of the returned object and make sure it matches the window handle you were expecting.

Comment: How are you instantiating and displaying the dialog?

Comment: Where _exactly_ does it crash ? Use the debugger. Look ate the call stack . Show us the call stack.

Comment: @MichaelWalz it's probably just trying to access members that aren't part of the actual object, due to the `(CPropertyPage *)` upcast. It used to be that MFC would keep a table of known window objects, and asking for an object associated with a window handle would return that object and the upcast would be safe. I haven't used MFC for a few years though, so I don't know if that mechanism has changed and I don't remember the specifics.

Comment: I think you are confusing the hierarchy. It seems to me your first `GetParent()` already returns the Property Sheet. What method is your code inside? If we don't know, we can't help!